# Spring RowMapper is being ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am calling my stored procedure like that:

```
        SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .returningResultSet("LookupResponse", new LookupMapper())
                .withProcedureName(lookupProcedureName);
```

and pass some parameters:

```
        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("id", request.getId())
            .addValue("Username", userName)
```

Code of the row mapper:

```
public class LookupMapper implements RowMapper<LookupResponse> {

    @Override
    public LookupResponse mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
        LookupResponse lookupResponse = new LookupResponse();
        lookupResponse.setDeviceId(rs.getInt("DeviceId"));
        lookupResponse.setApplicationId(rs.getInt("AppId"));
        return lookupResponse;
    }
}
```

Then I call the DB:

```
Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in);
```

I see unmapped key-value pairs in the returned map, and when I do:

```
(Collection<LookupResponse>) out.get("LookupResponse");
```

it returns null.

There is no key with my row mapped response.
The same kind of code works with another stored procedure... I don't understand what might be the reason. No exceptions in console, the rowMapper just being ignored. Please, help me understand.

Comment: Where's the code for `LookupMapper`?

Comment: @JimGarrison added, please take a look

Comment: Put a breakpoint in mapRow and see what's happening.

Comment: @tgdavies nothing is happening, it doesn't enter that method

Comment: Then perhaps your stored procedure isn't returning any rows, or `"LookupResponse"` doesn't match the name of the results/cursor.

Comment: @tgdavies it returns results but in this way: `SELECT @DeviceID = t.device_id, @ApplicationID = t.app_id` ..., so I assume the reason is that it assigns variables to the result

Comment: did you figure this out? I am having the same issue

Comment: @Arya I think the problem was with what stored procedure was returning, I couldn't change it that's why I decided not to use rowmapper and map manually

Answer (score 0):

Change as per below
`Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in);`
to
`Map<String, Object> outMap = jdbcCall.withReturnValue().execute(in);`

Comment: But there is no mapper being specified in your code, my main problem is that mapper is not being called

Comment: Just replace your db call code and see if u get keys in response

Comment: Yes, as I said I see key-value pairs in the returned map, the problem is rowmapper is not called, so all these values are unmapped

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Do this to troubleshoot

`System.out.println(out);`

Make sure the string starts with "LookupResponse"

`{LookupResponse=[...`

if not replace it accordingly